# How to get array's element type size in D?

Tags: d

Say, I have an array: int[] a = ... And I want to get size of its element. I can do something like this: a.sizeof / a.length, but it looks a bit complex and I think there is a way to do something like this: ArrayLementType!(a).sizeof. How does "ArrayLementType" looks in D?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply get the `typeof` one of the elements and `sizeof` that

```
typeof!(a[0]).sizeof
```

Otherwise there is [std.range.ElementType](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_range.html#ElementType) to get the type of any range (which includes arrays